# solution of $y(xy+1)dx+x(1+xy+x^2y^2)dy = 0$

Tags: calculus

solve $y(xy+1)dx+x(1+xy+x^2y^2)dy = 0$

writting differential equation $xy^2dx+ydx+xdy+x^2ydy+x^3y^2dy =0$

$xy(ydx+xdy)+(ydx+xdy)+x^3y^2dy=0$

$(1+xy)d(xy)+x^3y^2dy=0$

could some help me with this, thanks

Comment: @DURGESHTIWARI: **Hint:** Let $y = \dfrac{v}{x} \implies y' = \dfrac{v'}{x} - \dfrac{v}{x^2}$.

Comment: @Moo if you wouldn't mind, could you please explain why this is the case? I'm curious.

Comment: Using this substitution makes the DEQ a Separable Equation and solvable. There could be other approaches.

Comment: @Moo wont the resultant integration be lengthy

Comment: The resulting integration is not bad, but you will not be able to solve it explicitly, but will get a closed-form implicit solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution (below) is obtained on the form of an implicit equation.

[image]

Then, it is not very difficult to explicit $x(y)$. But it seems not possible to get a closed form for the inverse function $y(x)$ with the available standard functions.